# Label at the end of XAMDataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a XAMDataGrid which is used to populate a report by the below code.

where EGMList is a model.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQkpR.jpg)

**Reports.Xaml**

```
 <dataPresenter:XamDataGrid x:Name="datagdStatus" DataSource="{Binding EgmList}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  GroupByAreaLocation="None" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="11" Visibility="Hidden">
                    <dataPresenter:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                        <dataPresenter:FieldLayoutSettings RecordSelectorLocation="None" AllowAddNew="False" AllowDelete="False"  AutoGenerateFields="False" />
                    </dataPresenter:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                    <dataPresenter:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts >
                        <dataPresenter:FieldLayout >
                            <dataPresenter:FieldLayout.Fields>
                                <dataPresenter:Field Name="Id" Label="{x:Static p:resource.tab_report_machineid}" Width="1.8*" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                        <dataPresenter:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" LabelTextAlignment="Center" EditorStyle="{StaticResource TextEditor}" LabelTextWrapping="Wrap"  />
                                    </dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                </dataPresenter:Field>
                                <dataPresenter:Field Name="MacAddress" Label= "{x:Static p:resource.UID}" Width="4*">
                                    <dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                        <dataPresenter:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" LabelTextAlignment="Left" LabelTextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    </dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                </dataPresenter:Field>
                                <dataPresenter:Field Name="HouseNumber" Label= "{x:Static p:resource.tab_chn_houseNumber_Title}" Width="3.3*" >
                                    <dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                        <dataPresenter:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" LabelTextAlignment="Left" />
                                    </dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                </dataPresenter:Field>
                                <dataPresenter:Field Name="Type" Label="{x:Static p:resource.tab_report_type}" Width="2.5*" >
                                    <dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                        <dataPresenter:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" LabelTextAlignment="Left" LabelTextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    </dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                </dataPresenter:Field>
                                <dataPresenter:Field Name="Status" Label="{x:Static p:resource.tab_redeem_status}" Width="5*" >
                                    <dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                        <dataPresenter:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" LabelTextAlignment="Left" />
                                    </dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                </dataPresenter:Field>
                           </dataPresenter:FieldLayout.Fields>

                        </dataPresenter:FieldLayout>

                    </dataPresenter:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>

                </dataPresenter:XamDataGrid>
            </DockPanel>
```

**Reports.Xaml.cs**

```
  private void btnAllStatusPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (RedeemVoucherViewModel.EgmList.Count != 0)
        {
            Report reportObj = new Report();
            // set scale mode
            reportObj.ReportSettings.HorizontalPaginationMode = HorizontalPaginationMode.Scale;
            reportObj.PageHeaderTemplate = this.Resources["PagePresenterHeaderTemplate_small"] as DataTemplate;
            //  reportObj.PageContentTemplate = this.TryFindResource("basicContentTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            string siteControllerName = RedeemVoucherView.getSiteControllerName();
           // reportObj.PageFooter = "Total Machines :23";
            reportObj.PageHeader = string.Format("{0} {2} {1}", siteControllerName, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), Environment.NewLine);
            reportObj.ReportSettings.PageSize = new Size(3.13, 6);
            // create section and add it to report's section collection
            reportObj.ReportSettings.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            EmbeddedVisualReportSection section = new EmbeddedVisualReportSection(datagdStatus);
            reportObj.Sections.Add(section);
            reportObj.Print(true, false);
            rteventLogger.WriteLog(TraceEventType.Information, "All Status report is printed", WMSTrace.ScopeTypes.Internal);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBoxHelper.Show("No content available to print", MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
    }
```

The Report is getting printed on the above function call and it populates the contents of the EGMList in the Report Grid.

I would like to have a Summary Label at the end of the report with a count of the records/EGMs

Tried adding it in the **PageFooter** but no luck as it prints in all the Pages.

Also tried adding a different section from code behind but that also displays taking a different page all together.

Any Suggestion on this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not an easy thing to do.

First I thought I just need to define a new `FooterTemplate` for the `Report` and hide or show the footer based on whether it's on the last page or not.

Unfortunately the report generation is done in a way that you don't know how many pages will be generated in total, so in the data template you don't know if you are templating the last page or not.

Source: [Source1](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/27584.aspx)

Source2: [Source2](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/83742.aspx)

#### Workaround

I can only offer you a workaround. If you don't mind generating the report twice it's doable.
First we generate it so we get the total number of pages and we can set the `FooterTemplate` using that:

```
private void btnAllStatusPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (RedeemVoucherViewModel.EgmList.Count != 0)
    {
        Report reportObj = new Report();
        // set scale mode
        reportObj.ReportSettings.HorizontalPaginationMode = HorizontalPaginationMode.Scale;
        reportObj.PageHeaderTemplate = this.Resources["PagePresenterHeaderTemplate_small"] as DataTemplate;
        string siteControllerName = RedeemVoucherView.getSiteControllerName();

        reportObj.PageFooter = string.Format("Total Machines: {0}", MyXamDataGrid.DataItems.Count);

        reportObj.PageHeader = string.Format("{0} {2} {1}", siteControllerName, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), Environment.NewLine);
        reportObj.ReportSettings.PageSize = new Size(3.13, 6);
        // create section and add it to report's section collection
        reportObj.ReportSettings.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        EmbeddedVisualReportSection section = new EmbeddedVisualReportSection(datagdStatus);
        reportObj.Sections.Add(section);

        var xamReportPreviewToGetTotalPageNumbers = new XamReportPreview();
        xamReportPreviewToGetTotalPageNumbers.GeneratePreview(reportObj, false, false);
        reportObj.PageFooterTemplate = GetDataTemplateForTotalPageNumbers(reportObj.PhysicalPageNumber);

        reportObj.Print(true, false);
        rteventLogger.WriteLog(TraceEventType.Information, "All Status report is printed", WMSTrace.ScopeTypes.Internal);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBoxHelper.Show("No content available to print", MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
}
```

And the `GetDataTemplateForTotalPageNumbers` is the following:

```
private DataTemplate GetDataTemplateForTotalPageNumbers(int totalPages)
{
    var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();

    //set up the label
    var labelFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof (Label)) {Name = "FooterLabel"};
    labelFactory.SetValue(VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed);
    labelFactory.SetValue(ContentProperty, new Binding());

    dataTemplate.VisualTree = labelFactory;

    var dataTrigger = new DataTrigger
    {
        Binding = new Binding("PhysicalPageNumber")
        {
            RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor)
            {
                AncestorType = typeof (ReportPagePresenter)
            }
        },
        Value = totalPages
    };

    dataTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter {
        TargetName = "FooterLabel",
        Property = VisibilityProperty,
        Value = Visibility.Visible
    });

    dataTemplate.Triggers.Add(dataTrigger);

    return dataTemplate;
}
```

I hope this helps. I would use this with caution though. Because now we're generating the report twice (once for getting the total page numbers and set the correct datatemplate which shows the footer on the correct page, and once again to print it) it causes twice the time, so if you have a huge grid, this would freeze the UI for a while.